# Java JNDI internals

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

I am trying to understand JNDI, and I cannot get to the bottom of things. From what I understand, JNDI is interface which enables you to retrieve objects from filesystem based on some configuration.

I mostly seen examples when there was defined `DataSource` with parameters, in `web.xml` or as `<Resource>` in `Tomcat`. Than, Java app can get this `DataSource` obejct instance via `initialContext` and by name specified in resource definition.

But what I woudl want to understand is, what happens in background? How does `JVM` know where to search for such resources? For exmaple, if defined in tomcat, I suppose it somehow exports them. But how does `JVM` knows it should ask Tomcat for them? And more, in case of `DataSource`, from JNDI lookup actuall object can be retrieved, with parameters set from resource definition (connection string, etc)... Wha´t component sets them? `Tomcat`? `JVM`? I am so confused...

Answer (score 1):

Using JNDI resource lookups in your Java code allows your application to be unaware of configuration details such as the address of an SMTP server or the username/password of a database. Instead, you decide on a name for each resource, which must be configured properly by the person that deploys your application. This separation of environment specific settings makes your application more portable, which is generally a good thing.

JNDI resources in Tomcat are configured in various XML files (server.xml, web.xml, context.xml), see the Tomcat documentation for details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html. The Tomcat server knows to read these files and provide the configured objects to your application when you do a JNDI lookup.